# Ubuntu is unresponsive and scrolling is very jerky

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've been using 12.04LTS for over a week now. For 3 days it was great but now I'm having a number of problems. I'm using an Acer Aspire one D255 it has a 250GB HDD and a 1GB Memory. My browser is Firefox. Pages freeze occasionally and I wait for over 10 minutes and have to use the computer's 'off' button. Pages crash. On facebook some pictures don't load and I have to close down and restart a couple of times. Scrolling can sometimes be very jerky. Downloading software has become a problem and I have a 'no entry' sign in the top taskbar. I've looked at this page for some help but the words used and the explanations are not helpful to someone like me who has little knowledge of this. Please - 'Ubuntu for dummies'. I'd like to continue using Ubuntu but am close to giving up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Acer Aspire one D255 is a low end netbook, I am afraid that the default Ubuntu interface 'Unity' is to heavy for your pc. I would suggest installing a more lightweight version of Ubuntu such as Lubuntu and/or Kubuntu. This changes completely how Ubuntu looks, but it can be done without reinstalling the computer.

If you're sure you want this, you can install it in the following way:

Go to the Ubuntu software center and search for Lubuntu-desktop if there are two you should install the one without the i386 label, which is the one for 64-bit systems like your laptop.

Restart and it should either boot into Lubuntu directly or present you with a login screen, click on the ubuntu logo above the login field and select Lubuntu from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As you've suggested I've tried to download the Lubuntu-desktop but I get the message: - "Package dependencies cannot be resolved". Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Minos. Perhaps I should also mention that I have the 64 bit version of ubuntu and I'm now not sure if this is the correct one for my netbook. Also I still have 'Windows' on my netbook although I don't intend to keep it for any longer than I need to.

Comment: To check if your cpu is suitable for a 64-bit operating system could you copy this into a command line window (press ctrl+alt+t): `grep --color=always -iw lm /proc/cpuinfo` and show me the output? you can copy and paste into the command line by clicking right mouse.

Comment: If you're currently running the 64-bits version, try installing the 64-bits version of lubuntu-desktop (so the one that doesn't say i386).

Comment: Here is the output from the command line: - flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm
flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm

Comment: It seems I was mistaken and your laptop does support 64-bit. It's the `lm` flag (Long Mode), so you're fine. Install Lubuntu-desktop without the i386 version. I have also updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if adobe-flashplugin and its dependencies are installed on your system. If not install the following two packages and restart system.

[image]

Comment: The attached screenshot is of synaptic which might not be installed on the OP computer. You can also open Ubuntu Software Center and type flash into the search box and install it from there. However I don't think this is the source of OP's problem.

Comment: Yes adobe-flash and dependencies are installed.